# What is robots.txt.dist used for?

Tags: joomla, robots.txt

In Joomla (CMS) the installation comes with a file called "robots.txt.dist". I know what robots.txt is used for, but don't know why a .dist version would exist. The install comes with a normal robots.txt which to me seems that makes the other file not needed.

Comment: Please not that joomla robots will prevent google from indexing your images folder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.dist files are usually just an example file to get you going but aren't intended to be used as the real thing.

Answer (score 5):

`.dist` means distribution. It's just sample of `robots.txt`. Normally, you should do `mv robots.txt.dist robots.txt` to set default `robots.txt` file, to make your website more search engines friendly. But text `dist` were added to not overwrite your current `robots.txt`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In this case it was to hide the installation folder from search engines.

Comment: You should never have an installation folder on a live site.